# how can I check tftpd log?

Tags: network

For macos built-in tftpd, I can not edit the config file `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist` which is readonly. So I can not add `-l` option to it. I would like to know the detail what tftpd does, downloading process etc.. How can I enable and check its log?

I tried to run `tail -f /var/log/system.log`, but it doesn't have any tftpd log. I tried `dmesg` too, but no tftpd log there either. Thanks a lot.

Btw, I don't find `tftp` tag, so I have no ideas which tag I should use.

Comment: Disable the daemon with launchctl, copy the plist and install an updated version in a directory you can write to?

Comment: Also, it logs through syslog, so even with `-l` you may need to adjust syslog settings as well.

Comment: @nohillside thanks for your reply. tftpd is protected by the system. I can't even run it with sudo. I don't know what you mean by installing an updated version. I tried many things, but none of them work...

Comment: It's not about  modifying tftp, it's about modifying the plist. Copy it, change the options there, and install your modified version of the plist in a LaunchDaemons directory you have write access to

Comment: @nohillside thanks for the clarification. I tried to put `~/Library/LaunchAgents/tftp.plist` this time and tftpd can be started with normal user. And I added `-l` option to it too. But there is still no log information in /var/log/system.log. I don't know how to adjust syslog setting to make it happen... Thanks.

Comment: It *should* log everything with the exception of the actual request. But I don't the setup currently to analye this in detail.